# Cannot load mod_passenger.so on OSX Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, osx-yosemite

I am trying to install Redmine 3.1.0 on my MacBook Pro (Yosemite) and it works fine with webrick. Unfortunately when I try to set up passenger to run Redmine with Apache2, Apache does not run and showing this message:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 499 of /opt/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
Syntax error on line 1 of
 /opt/local/apache2/conf/extra/mod_passenger.conf: Cannot load
 /Users/mickey9801/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.15/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so into server:

dlopen(/Users/mickey9801/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.15/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so, 10): 
Symbol not found: _ap_log_error_\n 
Referenced from: /Users/mickey9801/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.15/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so\n 
Expected in: flat namespace\n in /Users/mickey9801/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.15/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

I have googled to find anyone having same symptoms but seems that no one got "Symbol not found: ap_log_error" error.

./bin/about is as below

```
sh: darcs: command not found
sh: hg: command not found
sh: cvs: command not found
sh: bzr: command not found
Environment:
Redmine version 3.1.0.stable
Ruby version 2.2.2-p95 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-darwin14]
Rails version 4.2.3
Environment production
Database adapter Mysql2
SCM:
Subversion 1.7.19
Git 2.5.0
Filesystem
Redmine plugins:
no plugin installed
```

Hope that anyone know the reason here. Thank you.

Comment: People with similar errors: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95717/error-starting-apache-httpd-2-4-4-configured-with-mod-jk

Comment: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201307.mbox/%3C51D9811E.6030904@kippdata.de%3E

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5657293?tstart=0

Comment: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.tomcat.user/238961

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/827937/apache-problems-after-upgrading-to-yosemite